# Magento2 css js minify

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, js-css, merge-css, minify

A stylesheet doesn't load good after the merge and minifies CSS and js.
Every CSS are explored! Used static-content deploy but not works.

Comment: it must conflict with other CSS and js try to change the order of CSS and js

Comment: How? and how can i find that witch one should be forst and more? @poojansharma